# Graphviz `failed to execute WindowsPath('dot')` but Environment Variable is Set

Tags: python, windows, graphviz

Error: `graphviz.backend.execute.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute WindowsPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH`

I installed graphviz from the main site using an installer for Windows 10

I used pip to install graphviz for Python 3.10.1

I have `C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin` in the `path` variable for both system and user.

What else should |I try please?

Sample code:

```
import graphviz

d = graphviz.Digraph(filename='rank_same.gv')

with d.subgraph() as s:
    s.attr(rank='same')
    s.node('A')
    s.node('X')

d.node('C')

with d.subgraph() as s:
    s.attr(rank='same')
    s.node('B')
    s.node('D')
    s.node('Y')

d.edges(['AB', 'AC', 'CD', 'XY'])

d.view()
```

Comment: Bring up a cmd window & type dot -V to check installation

Comment: dot - graphviz version 6.0.2 (20221011.1828)

Comment: The good news: the Graphviz system seems to be correctly.   So it seems to be a python/graphviz problem (duh).  Look here: https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/